# Is this design thread safe?

Tags: c#, concurrency, thread-safety

In c#, the main class created a Logger object that will be accessed by many threads. The logger object looks like (simplified)

```
public sealed class Logger
{
    private ConcurrentQueue<string> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();

    public Logger()
    {
        // create other objects here AND a thread that extracts
        // from the queue and writes to a file
        // because queue is thread safe this is perfectly ok
    }

   public void Log(string whatToLog)
   {
       // Now, is this safe? This method will be called by several threads
       // perhaps at the same time

       string s = whatToLog + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
       queue.Enqueue(s);

       // The thread created in the constructor will extract and log
   }
}
```

Is this OK from a design point of view? My two questions are:

- Is "string s = whatToLog + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString();" ok if this method is accessed by several threads at the same time? I guess yes because any thread will have its own copy of s, right?
- If the Logger object is accessed by several threads at the same time using only the Log() method, is everything safe then?

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried to test it? `ConcurrentQueue` was designed exactly for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ConcurrentQueue` will make sure that the queue-part will be thread safe.
The string `s` you construct will not make it more or less thread-safe

- In the current form, you should instantiate the logger, and pass the reference to each thread that will use this class
- Although thread-safe, it does not guarantee sequentiality of the items
- Queues cannot grow infinitely, make sure that your mechanism to dequeue can keep up

Improvements:

- Make the class static, easier access for several threads
- Separate concerns on reading and writing; this can be done by making several essential function `internal` and placing classes in the same namespace
- use C#6 string interpolation

Code with improvements

```
public static class Logger
{
    private static ConcurrentQueue<string> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();

    public static void Log(string LogMessage)
    {
        // thread safe logging
        queue.Enqueue($"{LogMessage} {DateTime.Now}");
    }


    //dequeue only within namespace
    internal static string Dequeue() {
        string dequeuedItem;
        queue.TryDequeue(out dequeuedItem);
        return dequeuedItem;
    }
}

public class LoggerReader
{
    public LoggerReader()
    {
        // create other objects here AND a thread that extracts
        // from the queue and writes to a file
        // because queue is thread safe this is perfectly ok
        string logItem = Logger.Dequeue();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The class is pretty thread safe.

Some suggested improvements.
The class doesn't prevent multiple instances from being instantiated, which is important if you want to have all threads log to the same object.  Perhaps the singleton pattern could be applied.  Quick example of a pseudo singleton using a static constructor.  Please note the default constructor is private preventing any other class from creating a logger.

A performance related change is to avoid concatenating strings when logging. Creating new string is not a cheap operation. Also, once DateTime.Now is converted to a string, it is much harder to evaluate. E.g. sorting messages by creation date and time, etc.  In the following, whatToLog is paired up with DateTime.Now in a Tuple.

```
public sealed class Logger
{
    public static Logger instance {get; private set;}
    static Logger()
    {
        instance = new Logger();
    }

    private ConcurrentQueue<Tuple<string, DateTime>> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<Tuple<string, DateTime>>();
    private Logger() {}

    public void Log(string whatToLog)
    {
       queue.Enqueue(new Tuple(whatToLog, DateTime.Now));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I know about the singleton pattern, and was thinking of implementing it. About the Tuple, yes but the writting thread must convert the DateTime to a string and craft a new string to log anyway, so this cannot be avoided.

Answer (score -2):

I would simply use a lock in the Log method (replace ConcurrentQueue by Queue), and would not worry about each instruction anymore, especially if the original logger is more complicated than the example here!

```
   public void Log(string whatToLog)
   {
       lock(queue) {
           string s = whatToLog + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
           queue.Enqueue(s);
       }    
   }
```

Comment: The `ConcurrentQueue`  class was specially designed so that people don't have to `lock` while accessing the queue.

Comment: Indeed the critical part is not ConcurrentQueue, but the method Log which will be called by many threads. Using lock at higher level makes things simpler imho. In this example, ConcurrentQueue could be replaced by Queue

Comment: This post does not answer question at all.

Comment: @DavidKalman Locking for the sake of the `string s = ...` is not neccessary?